# import item to dspace is time consuming problem

Tags: dspace

I have a problem with ItemImport via Adding Items to a Collection from a zip file. The problem is that the total time the script spends to run is not reasonable. Each import using the command line script takes 1-2s. I think this time is reasonable. the problem is that at the beginning of the ScriptLauncher, starting the kernel is taking about 3 seconds. therefore the total elapsed time for each import is about 5 second. This 5 second is not reasonable. I use DSpace dspace3.x on a centos system with 40GB RAM and eight CPU core.

Do you have any idea about how I can solve the problem? I insist on using import Item via single zip file at a time and NOT using the batch import.

Comment: It sounds like you have a very powerful server for running DSpace, so your resources should be adequate.  I recommend that you ensure that both tomcat and your import task are allocated some of that RAM.  JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx4000m.

Comment: These recommendations might also be helpful.  https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC3x/Performance+Tuning+DSpace

Comment: fewer and fewer people these days are running DSpace 3.x in PROD, so you may find it difficult to find people who can reproduce the problem like this. Even though this may not be an option for you right now, I would highly recommend to upgrade to 5.x or 6.x

Comment: I have already configured and optimized the setting.  Java, PostgreSQL, and tomcat have enough resources. actually, we have a plan to upgrade to DSpace 6.x. unfortunately, this issue also exists in the upper versions of DSpace.